# Hide element on mouseleave (only when moving fast?)

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, mouseout

I am trying to make a button disappear when moving my mouse out of a box. However, the button only is disappearing when I move my mouse fast. If I move the mouse slowly out of the box then the button still exists outside the box. How can I fix this?

```js
$('.moveBox').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
  $('.moveBut').css({
    left: e.pageX + 20,
    top: e.pageY + 20
  })
})

$('.moveBut').hide();

$('.moveBox').on('mouseenter', function() {
  $('.moveBut').show();
});

$('.moveBox').on('mouseleave', function() {
  $('.moveBut').hide(10);
});
```

```css
.moveBox {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: pink;
}

.moveBut {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moveBox">
  <button class="moveBut">hello</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/evibreukers/pen/XWbMerd

Comment: The issue is because the mouseover is on the button, not the box. As such the `mouseleave` never fires because the element moves with the mouse, *unless* you move quickly and the JS can't keep up.To fix this you could set the event on the `moveBox` and use `pointer-events: none` on the button: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ju5enkgv/. The problem with that solution is whether you expect the button to be clickable or not.